# How page layout assignments are evaluated

Tags: case, profile, page-layout, record-type

I'm fairly new to salesforce. So please bear with me if this question turns out to be quite basic.

I've been doing the migration project from salesforce to Dynamics CRM online and one of the modules to be migrated is Case.

In salesforce, the case module seems to be heavily customized with 20 something profiles, record types and page layouts. So the page layout matrix is quite huge and complex (at least for me). So far I've figured out that each profile can be assigned record types (one of these can be set as default) and the page layout assigned to that record type will be shown to the user. But it looks like users can see other page layouts outside the record types assigned.

To give an example, I have profile, **'Profile A'**, with only one record type **'Record Type A'** assigned to this profile. The page layout assigned is **'Case Layout A'**. But this page layout is only shown during creation of the case. Once the case is saved and the user clicked Edit, it's showing another layout, **'Saved Case Layout B'**, whose record type is not added to the **'Profile A'** at all.

How exactly is this page layout definition evaluated? Am I missing some other rule setting? I've scoured through salesforce documentation and the only articles I can find are for simple scenarios or how to create basic assignment scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If that is the case, check if Edit Button is overridden with visualforce or URL.

Comment: It seems it's just standard Edit button. I found out some workflows setting the recordtypeid internally. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here this can happen because of some workflow rules (Guess! It can be anything which can do a business logic e.g. Process Builder, Trigger, Apex, ..) written on the **case** object which changes the record type to **Saved Case Layout B** once the record type is saved.

The question is little bit unclear, please elaborate what is the problem you are facing and I can help you with anything.

Comment: Thanks! There's about 50 workflows for case and some of them are setting recordtypeid (which I'm guessing is internal field) based on some criteria.

The problem I'm facing is that I have to figure out and consolidate the whole case process for each profiles. So I need to know what are the configurations that cause the layout or picklists to be different.

I will also take a look at other modules as you mentioned.

Comment: You can check the workflow rules and find the record type names from the Ids mentioned in them by putting the id in salesforce URL. "https://<anything>.salesforce.com/**<Put the ID here>**"

Comment: You can also use the debug logs to check the complete flow and order of execution of buisness logic step by step. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_debugging_debug_log.htm